# Error with biber with MacTex 2023

Tags: miktex, biber, mac, mactex

I'm having issues with biber even using the simplest code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{fittizio,
  author     = {Paolo Polesana},
  title      = {De Polesanis},
  year       = {1980},
  edition    = {2},
  publisher  = {s.n.},
  location   = {Bresso},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{fittizio}

\end{document}
```

After running the bibliography compiler I get this error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools),
missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Looks like the compiler does not find biber at all. I'm using MacTex and I compile my files through TexShop. I set in the preferences `biber` to compile my bibliography as in the picture:

[image]

Seems it's an installation problem: I recently installed the newest (2023) version of Tex Live. The 2020 version is working.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: I also have the same issue after installing 2023 from 2021.

Comment: Try install command line tools from Apple using `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Thanks! Now it’s working